# Where to place Rails code that is not a model, view, controller or helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I want to share code not related to views between several controllers in my Rails app. Where in the directory structure should I place it?

EDIT: the code in question if something all controllers use to determine *how* they render the model data

Comment: it's not related to database entities, either (so not model code)

Comment: Models don't need to be database related.  They just represent data used by the system, regardless of if it is stored or not.

Comment: What is it? You only state what it is not, but not what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the code is something like modules with utility methods in these could be placed in the `lib` folder. Alternatively you could create a common superclass for some of your controllers if they share behaviour.

Please post an example of the kind of code you're thinking of.

Answer (score 5):

If it's "something all controllers use", I would place it in a base class used by all controllers.  The "application_controller" comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I have been creating modules in lib to provide code to other classes.

Here's an abbreviated example module that defines values for views that can be instantiated from different controllers.

```
module ControllerDefaultValues
  def default_value_for_some_controller()
    @controller_name = "some_controller"
  end
end
```

To use this, simply include the module in your class:

```
class SearchesController
  include ControllerDefaultValues
  #
  def search_some_controller
    default_value_for_some_controller()
    render(:partial => "search_results")
  end
end
```

The main benefit of this method is it keeps your controllers directory focused on controllers and your models directory focused on logic.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i think its fine, if its controller related to put it in your controllers directory, but, labelled as a module, e.g. `app/controllers/what_am_i_module.rb` since it is specific to the application in development.

lib seems like a place to me where i would put framework/core enhancements or monkey patches which are non-specific to the application.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be used by all your controllers, stick it in application_controller.rb

All your controllers inherit from ApplicationController, so they'll all have access to them.